# batch - request user input depending on initial user input

Tags: windows, batch-file

In Windows batch, I'm asking the user whether he wants to use the program's internal default or wants to set his own parameters, but no matter what the user sets as an answer, the program always jumps straight to the main routine using the internal defaults. This is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

choice /C:yn /M "Use internal defaults? "
if errorlevel==1 goto yes
if errorlevel==2 goto no

rem use default
:yes 
set "MYNUMBER=5"
goto run

rem let user define another number
:no
set /P MYNUMBER="Please set a number: "
goto run

rem main routine
:run
echo %MYNUMBER%
pause
```

What am I missing?

And since we're at it: how can I force the program to wait for the user to hit "Enter" after typing his choice? Right now, it starts directly after typing "y" or "n".

Comment: Using your syntax you have to reverse the order, `if errorlevel==1` implies if errorlevel equal 1 or greater. A different thing is using the environment variable `%errorlevel%` as long the var isn't altered (by another error) you can check for a distinct value. See`Help if`or view [onlne](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: `if errorlevel==1` is completely wrong syntax. The correct syntax can be read by opening a cmd window and run the command `if /?` which outputs the help of command __IF__ explaining on first help page the correct syntax `if [not] errorlevel number command`. There is no string comparison operator `==`. And this condition is true if exit code of previous command or application is __greater or equal__ the number. So use first `if errorlevel 2 goto no` and no more `if` is needed because next command lines to execute on exit code being not greater or equal 2 are the lines for user choice `y`.

Comment: To await {Enter}, use [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) instead of `choice`; but then also account for invalid user input...

Comment: The `errorlevel` was not obvious to me. Now, using `set /P USER_CHOICE="Use defaults? (Y/N)"` and then checking it using `if` does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the commentators, that helped a lot! Now its working like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:ask
set /P USER_CHOICE="Use internal defaults? (Y/N) "

if /i "%USER_CHOICE%"=="y" (
    goto yes
    ) else (
    if /i "%USER_CHOICE%"=="n" (
        goto no
        ) else (
        echo "Wrong input! Please choose Y or N!"
        goto ask
    )
)

rem use default
:yes 
set "MYNUMBER=5"
goto run

rem let user define another number
:no
set /P MYNUMBER="Please set a number: "
goto run

rem main routine
:run
echo %MYNUMBER%
pause
```

Comment: why not `set USER_CHOICE=5`, `set /p USER_CHOICE=Please set a number (empty for default [%USER_CHOICE%])`

Comment: For that very basic example, this would work as well, for sure. But in my real case, I have multiple values that can be set by the user or he can just leave them at their defaults, that's why I chose this way.